# .Net System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache - Store a single collection or individual custom objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, .net-4.0, memorycache

I am implementing caching using MemoryCache (.net 4.0) for caching global data which will be used by all users of my website.

**My initial approach:**
Store a KeyedCollection which would hold a collection of the  Customer objects with a key to get a single object. This collection could have up to 250 such objects. Whenever the cache expires, I would rebuild the KeyedCollection and add it to the cache.

**New approach**
Now, I am thinking why not store each Customer object directly to the cache with the customerid as the look-up key. Therefore, MemoryCache.Default would have upto 250 such Customer objects versus a single KeyedCollection. 
Benefits:

1. More efficient since I will get the Customer object directly from
   the cache without having to perform another look-up on the Keyed
   Collection.
2. I would add a new Customer object to the cache only when it is
   requested for the first time. Sort of lazy addition as opposed to
   pre-building the entire cache.

Any thoughts on using one versus the other in terms of performance and other factors?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built-in ASP.NET cache?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Comment: I am using the built-in MemoryCache (System.Runtime.Caching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution will depend on how often you need to work on the objects as a collection.

Reasons for storing as a collection:

- Storing each object individually, if all 250 objects are always
  populated, take up more space, as each item in cache would have an
  associated `CacheItemPolicy`.  This case is probably unlikely,
  however.
- You would not have *strongly typed* extension methods made
  available by Linq on collections. (The extension methods are
  available, but MemoryCache items are exposed as `KeyValuePair<string,
  object>`).

Reasons for storing individually:

- You are only or mostly going to be working one a single object at a time.
- You want each object to be created and removed from cache based on its own frequency of usage, rather than that of a whole collection.

So, compare your likely usage scenario, and choose accordingly. Chances are, unless you are writing lots of `.Where`, `.Select`, etc, calls or have reason to pass around the whole collection, then storing individually is going to be the better choice.

Comment: Are there noticeable performance implications of having a CacheItemPolicy for each object? I figured 250 objects is a very modest number and should have no issues. Every web request will only use a single object. Therefore I don't like the idea of getting the collection from the cache and doing a look-up for every request.

Comment: I can't say with complete certainty, but I would learn towards, no, that the extra overhead of handling the object in cache should be negligible. It will certainly be unnoticeable in your case.